# COPY/ADD command in Dockerfile is not copying .gitignored folder

Tags: docker

I have a folder called `public`

which is gitignored.

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

ADD public /usr/share/nginx/public/
# COPY public /usr/share/nginx/public/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Now when I create image, I get this error

```
Step 2/3 : COPY public /usr/share/nginx/public/
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat public: file does not exist
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I figured out if I exclude `public` folder from gitignore then all is good.

I checked there is no `.dockerignore` file.
Just make sure if it's fallback issue, I created a new `.dockerignore` file with empty content

Comment: Try using "./public" instead of "public" to ensure that docker knows its a directory not a file and make sure the public folder is in the same directory as the Dockerfile

Comment: @Yoh tried, same issue
When I remove the public from gitignore, it works perefectly even with no `./` at begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure it out, I was using `gcloud build` command to create docker file, and seems google by default ignores gitignore files.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

so I created a `.gcloudignore` file with below content

```
*

!public
```